# I want to add a class to an iframe based on finding a specific class within the html of that iframe

Tags: javascript, css, class, iframe

I am trying to add a class to an iframe on the condition that the body tag class is a specific class name. I wrote some code based on my limited knowledge:

```
<iframe class='iframeContent' src='' width='100%' height='' frameborder='0'>
</iframe>

if ($('.iframeContent').contents().find('body').hasClass('alaska')) {
                    $('iframe').addClass('iframe-cont');                    
}
```

Please help. My javascript skills are not very good and just need some direction.

Comment: Where are you using above code? I think you should use load event of iframe to validate and add class

Comment: if ($('body').hasClass('alaska')) {
                    $('iframe').addClass('iframe-cont');                    
}
This should do,but your question is not very clear, maybe you should update that and eplain in more detail

Comment: Sorry if I was a bit vague. I have a page that loads iframes dynamically so depending on which iframe is being loaded I need to target that iframe and add a class. so I've added classes to the body of the iframe content so that I can identify which iframe is loaded. this will allow me to add unique classes to the iframe that relate to the specific iframe content. I hope I'm not confusing things further?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may not be able to access content from the iframe. That depends on a lot of browser security details which I will not get into. If you are on the same domain, you may be able to.

If you *do* have access, the method you describe should work. It's exactly what the [printThis](https://github.com/jasonday/printThis) plugin does.